# Assert that every object property matches given predicate in kotlin test

Tags: kotlin, assertion, kotlintest, kotest

I have a collection of objects:

```kotlin
data class WeatherForecast(
    val city: String,
    val forecast: String
    // ...
)
```

I would like to test that each and every item matches given predicate on field.

Is there any assertion in `kotlintest assertions` that will allow me to do so?

Something like:

```kotlin
 forecasts.eachItemshouldMatch{ it.forecast == "SUNNY" }
```

Comment: As far as I can see in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/kotlin.test/kotlin.test/) of `kotlin.test` there seems to be no way to collect the result of multiple assertions. With JUnit5 you would be able to use `assertAll`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using an inspector.

```kotlin
list.forAll {
  it.forecast shouldBe "SUNNY"
}
```

https://kotest.io/docs/assertions/inspectors.html

Answer (score -2):

You can simply use the `all` function; i.e.:

```kotlin
forecasts.all { it.forecast == "SUNNY" }
```

Comment: I would like to have information from the assertion on which items did not met the criteria

Comment: Is `forecasts.filterNot()` would satisfy your expectations @pixel?